# how do I create a custom npm command like create-react-app?

Tags: npm, automation

I want to make a command like create-react-app, but using my own configuration, I want to install the dependencies and create their config files, folders, etc... all in one command.

for example : `npm create-my-own-app`

does anyone have any idea on how to do that ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.